# Unable to load libstdc++.so.5 on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, libraries

I'm trying to execute a binary and it says `./xtensoftphone: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. This library is indeed installed under `/usr/lib`. Is there something I need to do to get the binary to see the library? I thought all `/usr/lib` libraries were visible.

---

```
blaine :: ~/Downloads/xten-xlite » ldd xtensoftphone                                                                                                                    
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf7783000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib32/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7749000)
libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib32/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0xf7743000)
libglade-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib32/libglade-2.0.so.0 (0xf772a000)
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib32/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0xf7355000)
libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib32/libxml2.so.2 (0xf722b000)
libz.so.1 => /usr/lib32/libz.so.1 (0xf7216000)
libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib32/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0xf7180000)
libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib32/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0xf7163000)
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib32/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0xf7149000)
libpangoxft-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib32/libpangoxft-1.0.so.0 (0xf7141000)
libpangox-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib32/libpangox-1.0.so.0 (0xf7134000)
libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib32/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0xf70f1000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib32/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0xf70b1000)
libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib32/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0xf70ac000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib32/libdl.so.2 (0xf70a8000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib32/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xf6fde000)
libm.so.6 => /lib32/libm.so.6 (0xf6fb8000)
libstdc++.so.5 => not found
libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf6f98000)
libc.so.6 => /lib32/libc.so.6 (0xf6e3e000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib32/libX11.so.6 (0xf6d21000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7784000)
librt.so.1 => /lib32/librt.so.1 (0xf6d18000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib32/libpcre.so.3 (0xf6ce7000)
libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib32/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0xf6cbf000)
libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib32/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0xf6cb3000)
libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib32/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0xf6c15000)
libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib32/libcairo.so.2 (0xf6b9b000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib32/libfreetype.so.6 (0xf6b25000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib32/libfontconfig.so.1 (0xf6af4000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib32/libXext.so.6 (0xf6ae4000)
libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib32/libXrender.so.1 (0xf6ada000)
libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib32/libXinerama.so.1 (0xf6ad6000)
libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib32/libXi.so.6 (0xf6ac8000)
libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib32/libXrandr.so.2 (0xf6abf000)
libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib32/libXcursor.so.1 (0xf6ab5000)
libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib32/libXcomposite.so.1 (0xf6ab1000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib32/libXdamage.so.1 (0xf6aad000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib32/libXfixes.so.3 (0xf6aa7000)
libXft.so.2 => /usr/lib32/libXft.so.2 (0xf6a92000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib32/libxcb.so.1 (0xf6a78000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib32/libresolv.so.2 (0xf6a64000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib32/libselinux.so.1 (0xf6a49000)
libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib32/libpixman-1.so.0 (0xf69ee000)
libdirectfb-1.2.so.0 => /usr/lib32/libdirectfb-1.2.so.0 (0xf6977000)
libfusion-1.2.so.0 => /usr/lib32/libfusion-1.2.so.0 (0xf696d000)
libdirect-1.2.so.0 => /usr/lib32/libdirect-1.2.so.0 (0xf6957000)
libpng12.so.0 => /lib32/libpng12.so.0 (0xf6932000)
libxcb-render-util.so.0 => /usr/lib32/libxcb-render-util.so.0 (0xf692c000)
libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib32/libxcb-render.so.0 (0xf6924000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib32/libexpat.so.1 (0xf68fd000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib32/libXau.so.6 (0xf68f9000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib32/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xf68f3000)
```

---

```
blaine :: ~/Downloads/xten-xlite » cat /etc/ld.so.conf
include /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf
```

Comment: apparently `xtensoftphone` is a 32-bit executable; do you have a 32-bit `libstdc++.so.5`, or only a 64-bit one? What does `file -L /usr/lib*/libstdc++.so.5` show?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really have `/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.5`, in addition to `/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6`? The two are not compatible (in the sense that a program that requires one won't work with the other, of course you can install both). You'll need to install the [`libstd++5` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/libstdc++5).

Ubuntu 10.04 no longer has `libstdc++5`, but if you need it, you can grab the package from the [backports repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports). It was reintroduced in subsequent releases.

Comment: I do have 5 and 6 installed. The program is not requiring both, only 5, as shown by the ldd output above.

Comment: I installed 5 from a .deb

Comment: @Blaine: do you have a 32-bit or 64-bit system? If you installed a 64-bit library from a .deb, it won't work with your 32-bit executable.

Comment: Just run `sudo apt-get install libstdc++5`

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `ldconfig` after each change to the libraries. If in doubt, just run it, it won't hurt if run too often.

If that does not fix it, please post the output of `ldd xtensoftphone` , and the contents of `/etc/ld.so.conf` (plus any files under `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`), then we'll see.

Comment: See details added above

Comment: For a library in `/usr/lib`, the package manager should have run `ldconfig`. For anyone with a similar problem: if you install a library manually, put it in `/usr/local/lib`, and run `ldconfig` afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the location of the library to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: -1 This is more likely to further complicate matters. Libraries under /usr/lib should be picked up without LD_LIBRARY_PATH.